# parsing JSON using "koush/ion" not working?

Tags: json, android-studio, jsonparser, ion-koush

*the JsonObject **json** is empty, but **result** in **onCompleted** function works fine and correctly returns json data but I can't use it outside the **oncompleted** function *

```
   final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
            Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + searchedWord)
                    .setHeader("X-Mashape-Key","I've hidden the Key !")
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                            Log.i("result: ","" + result);
                            Log.i("json: ", "" + json);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the first line?

```
final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
```

Comment: You are right. it's redundant. but you didn't answer my question!

Comment: private JsonObject word; and in onCompleted callback, set word = result; Then you can use word outside of onCompleted.